# Flex-item image not honoring proportionality settings

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using CSS to style "cards".  I want to control the size of the "text area" and the "image area" of each card simply by specifying a `flex: n` setting.  In my [codepen](https://codepen.io/brentarias/pen/LYXXXyL),  I have made these settings:

```
  >img {
    flex: 1;
    object-fit: cover;
  }

  // This 'div' is for the text area...
  >div {
    flex: 2; 
  }
```

Based on these values, I expect the "text area" to be twice the size of the image.  Unfortunately, the image is large and will not shrink regardless of the `flex: 1` setting.  Without generating a new image of smaller size, what can I do to coerce the browser to resize the image to obey the `flex: n` settings I'm providing?

If I supply an image that is much smaller, then finally the `flex: n` settings are obeyed.  The image will actually grow, if needed, to be obey those settings.  If the CSS engine is willing to make the image grow to fit, why will it not also cause it to shrink to fit?  Anyway, again, I'm looking for a solution that does not require I regenerate the image as a smaller size.

I am looking for a purely CSS solution.

### Update

With help from comments, I've learned that my codepen works properly if (1) it is rendered in Firefox and (2) I add a `width: 100%` property to the `img` CSS selector.  However, that still doesn't fix the problem in chrome.

So in the meantime I've come up with a strange work-around.  First, I replace my `img` tag altogether...using instead this:

```
<div class="photo" 
  style="background-image: url(https://storage.googleapis.com/chydlx/codepen/blog-cards/image-1.jpg)"
</div>
```

Then I adjust my CSS selector to look as follows:

```
    >.photo {
        flex: 1;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        align-self:stretch;
    }
```

It is the `align-self` property that is the key "secret-sauce" for this particular trick to work.

That said, I'm very surprised that Chrome apparently isn't handling this flexbox rendering very well. I'd otherwise assume that flexbox rendering is a VERY solved problem.

I don't really consider my work-around to be my answer.  I'm hoping there is still an even "smarter" way to handle this.  Ideas?

Comment: The image needs `width: 100%` to allow it to resize to available space. `flex: 1` defaults to `1 1 0%`, essentially forcing the image to retain its original size.

Comment: @RenevanderLende adding `width: 100%` to the image selector didn't change anything...as if I didn't add it at all. :(

Comment: That's odd. Using your Pen I just added `width: 100%;` to `> img { ... }`  and it works fine for me in Firefox/W10 (just did it again to double check). here's my [fork](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/vYvYweX) (CSS line 28, not pretty but it works). Changed `> div { flex: 5 }` back to `2` again ( `> div { flex: 1 }` will work too).

Comment: @RenevanderLende Used your fork, and attempted in both Chrome and Firefox.  Same result...as if nothing had changed at all.  Try shrinking your browser down, so that it is not full screen...perhaps almost tablet size.  The image refuses to be anything other than its original size in pixels...regardless of any changes to `flex: n` for either the `>div` or `>img`.

Comment: Can't resize browser smaller than [this](https://i.postimg.cc/sDw89V84/Screenshot-2023-08-20-at-02-45-23-Chat-GPT-Cards-2.png). As you can see, works as advertised... (no changes made in my fork).

Comment: Tested Chrome and it shows reluctance to properly resize. I know Firefox has nested CSS support behind a `about:config` setting: **layout.css.nesting.enabled**, default is 'false' (set it 'true' in my Firefox). Maybe Chrome has issues with nesting CSS too??

Comment: @RenevanderLende Holy smokes!  By changing that Firefox "nested CSS" setting...it started working!  And, like you, no success with Chrome.  However, it is easy to prove that Chrome is indeed honoring the nested CSS.  That said, I kinda found a Chrome work-around; I replace the `img` tag with a `div class=".photo" style="background-image: url(...)"` setup and then set an `align-self: stretch` on the `.photo`.  I will update my question with this finding, though I'm not sure what to make of this...I would not expect this kind of aberrant behavior between browsers for flexbox.

Comment: Can't remember when I started working around flexbox child `<img>` element issues. I usually put them inside either a `<tag>` or use them as a `background-image` like you did now. Overall support for nested CSS rules is still at ~72%, with poor mobile support. I'd wait another 6-12 months before using them in production. While a nice feature, it does not add much when you're a meticulous and consistent pro developer... Browse my [N-Grid pens](https://codepen.io/your-work?search_term=n-grid). Might give you some ideas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254976/discussion-between-brent-arias-and-rene-van-der-lende).